# After rewriting, nginx doesn't use php-fastcgi

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, rewrite, php-fpm, ubuntu-13.04

I'm having trouble with an nginx rewrite. I want to rewrite `^(.*?)/(.*?)/?$` to `controllers/$1.php?action=$2`. This worked for me on an Apache server earlier. After that, I want to route that file to php-fastcgi.

For a normal request (i.e. when I type in the full path, without using a rewrite), php-fastcgi works normally.

My configuration:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;

    root            /var/www/my-dir;
    index           index.php index.html index.htm;
    charset         utf-8;

    server_name         my-domain;

    location / {
        autoindex   off;
        rewrite     ^(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ controllers/$1.php?action=$2 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        include     fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny        all;
    }
}
```

After editing this configuration, I did a `service nginx restart`, of course.

For some reason the location block for php-fastcgi isn't used after the rewrite. Why is that & how to resolve it?

Instead, I'm getting a "No input file specified" as a response. In the error log, I see:

```
2013/06/01 19:00:25 [error] 14288#0: *1 access forbidden by rule, client: xxx, server: my-domain, request: "GET /user/create HTTP/1.1", host: "my-domain"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/r/try_files).

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    # ....everything else
}
```

You might also have a problem with the `rewrite` since you don't have a `/` at the beginning of the relative URL `controllers/$1.php...`. Try changing that to `/controllers/$1.php...`.

And, you're missing a fastcgi parameter that tells php-fpm where to find the PHP script. Add this into the `location ~ \.php$` block.

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```